# OpenAPI specification for calDAV?

Tags: icalendar, openapi, caldav

I'm about to embark on some work around a [calDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) server implementation. calDAV is specified in a series of RFC:

- [rfc4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918): HTTP Extensions for Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV)
- [rfc4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791): Calendaring Extensions to WebDAV (CalDAV)
- [rfc5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545): iCalendar
- [rfc6638](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638): Scheduling Extensions to CalDAV
- [caldav-ctag-02](https://trac.calendarserver.org/browser/CalendarServer/trunk/doc/Extensions/caldav-ctag.txt): Calendar Collection Entity Tag (CTag) in CalDAV

(Shamelessly lifted from [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide))

At the end it is "just" `http` calls to specified URLs with a specified payload. I wonder: is there a ready made [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/) spec for calDAV or do I have to create my own?

Comment: Does Google give any hints?

Comment: @EwaldBenes Nope. Neither Google, lmgtfy or ChatGPT have an hint

Comment: I'm doing an iCloud CalDav integration into an app. The specs are quite big and complex. One problem is that each of the providers out there like iCloud, Google, Microsoft, etc. interpret the specification slightly different or add custom extensions.

They aren't totally different but could make writing such an OpenAPI spec less useful. Maybe it's the reason why nobody bothered writing an OpenAPI spec for it yet. Just a guess though.

Comment: @EwaldBenes I feel your pain. It almost feeld the difference in interpretation are deliberate